# qgis.pyQt5 button role returns different values on definition and button activation

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, pyqt5

The Goal is to implement 3 Buttons in pyQt5. The returned Values differ from the defined roles values. The returned values seem to depend on the order, the buttons are added. What is happening here?

```py
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QAction, QMessageBox, QPushButton



def button_tester():
    # check if annotation has not been cperformed
    # and additional redo annotation
    mb = QMessageBox()
    mb.setText('your choice please')
    
    mb.addButton(QPushButton('Yes'), QMessageBox.YesRole)
    mb.addButton(QPushButton('No'), QMessageBox.NoRole) 
    mb.addButton(QPushButton('Cancel'), QMessageBox.RejectRole)
    return_value = mb.exec()
    print("return_value",return_value) #--> 0 for YesRole, 1 for NoRole, 2 for RejectRole
    print("QMessageBox.YesRole",QMessageBox.YesRole)  #-->QMessageBox.YesRole 5
    print("QMessageBox.NoRole",QMessageBox.NoRole) #-->QMessageBox.NoRole 6
    print("QMessageBox.RejectRole",QMessageBox.RejectRole) #-->QMessageBox.RejectRole 1
    if return_value == QMessageBox.YesRole:
        print("Yes")
    elif return_value == QMessageBox.NoRole:
        print('No')
        
    elif return_value == QMessageBox.RejectRole:
        print('Cancel')
        
annotate_action = QAction("Button")
annotate_action.triggered.connect(button_tester)

anotate_toolbar = iface.addToolBar("Anotate Features")
anotate_toolbar.addAction(annotate_action)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Qt dcumentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#advanced-usage), the `QMessageBox::ButtonRole` is only used to place the custom button you want to add at a certain position in your `QMessageBox`.

> The ButtonRole is used by QMessageBox to determine the ordering of the buttons on screen (which varies according to the platform).

That's why if you change your code order from this :

```
mb.addButton(QPushButton('Yes'), QMessageBox.YesRole)
mb.addButton(QPushButton('No'), QMessageBox.NoRole) 
mb.addButton(QPushButton('Cancel'), QMessageBox.RejectRole)
```

To this :

```
mb.addButton(QPushButton('Cancel'), QMessageBox.RejectRole)
mb.addButton(QPushButton('No'), QMessageBox.NoRole) 
mb.addButton(QPushButton('Yes'), QMessageBox.YesRole)
```

The output is always goig to look like this :

[image]

If you want to have a specific value you should use the `QMessageBox::StandardButton`. Like specified in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#details) :

> The buttons are specified by combining values from StandardButtons using the bitwise OR operator.

So your function should look like this :

```
def button_tester():
    # check if annotation has not been cperformed
    # and additional redo annotation
    mb = QMessageBox()
    mb.setText('your choice please')
    mb.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Yes|QMessageBox.No|QMessageBox.Cancel)
    return_value = mb.exec()
    print("return_value",return_value)
    print("QMessageBox.Yes",QMessageBox.Yes)
    print("QMessageBox.No",QMessageBox.No)
    print("QMessageBox.Cancel",QMessageBox.Cancel)
    if return_value == QMessageBox.Yes:
        print("Yes")
    elif return_value == QMessageBox.No:
        print('No')
    elif return_value == QMessageBox.Cancel:
        print('Cancel')
```